# 'XXX' file not found after pod install

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

After I added AppnextNativeAdsSdk and ran `pod install`, my imports won't work.

The wired thing is the file that complains about 'not finding the AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h file is one of the sdk files - AppnextNativeAdsSDKApi.h.

The screenshot is here:

[image]

You can notice that the AppnextNativeAdsSDKApi.h file isn't showing it's directory like normal files do.

Possibly correct behavior:

[image]

---

### UPDATE

I figured out why this happened with the help of the Git version control.

Git shows that the last compilable commit import AppnextNativeAdsSdk in this way: `#import <AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h>` rather than: `#import <AppnextSDKCore/AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h>`.

Well, in order to control all third-party pods, we have our own pod repositories. So, AppnextNativeAdsSdk was actually wrapped as PGV-AppnextSDK. And the pod spec file is specified like this:

[image]

So, when cocoapods install PGV-AppnextSDK, all header files are included in `PGV-AppnextSDK` folder. There is no subdirectory as `AppnextSDKCore` or `AppnextNativeAdsSDK`.

So, when import `AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h` as `#import <AppnextSDKCore/AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h>`, the compiler is not happy. But, `#import <AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h>` will do the trick.

But, this `#import <AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h>` is somewhat confusing. Shouldn't it be `#import "AppnextSDKCorePublicDefs.h"`??

Comment: Show your Podfile please.

Comment: This file is actually inside AppnextSDKCore, which is a separate framework from AppnextNativeAdsSdk. Could you show the extract of your Podfile.lock to make sure that both frameworks are present?

Comment: Also please add the exact error message that you get form Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @battlmonstr. I think I figured out why this happened. Both frameworks are present for sure.

Comment: That's good. How did you scramble your screenshot? Looks cool.

Comment: @battlmonstr I am using one of the embedded utility tools of WetChat work app. But, Evernote has a very powerful and also free screen capture tool called: Skitch.

https://evernote.com/products/skitch